# Getting random degrees() for PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, random

Performing research on a new Python script to use in QGIS where I need to create a random point based on another point. This new point will need to have its location based on a random degree (two user inputs with a range from 0 to 360 degrees), as well as a random distance in meters from the original point (two user inputs from 1 to 100 meters).  The result should be a new layer or appending an existing layer.

Been finding some snippets of code I think I can start with but searched pyQGIS cookbook and python in general but so far no luck regarding random degrees.

Is there some sort of function for a random degrees selection?

Comment: you can try generating a random number in a range of 360 with `>>> from random import SystemRandom >>> srand = SystemRandom() >>> degree = srand.choice(range(360))`

Comment: Thx for such a quick reply.  Can I apply your answer and adjust for a random distance such as: >>> meters = srand.choice(range(100))

Comment: Depends whether you want to have float or integer. If an integer, then `>>> meters = srand.choice(range(100))`. If float then `>>> meters = round(random.uniform(0,100.00), 2))`